# Wordpress woocommerce: Display specyfic subcategories on frontpage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a woocommerce and it's own categories system. I've got one category named "types" which containts several others child categories. System automatically genetared a gallery with images and links to those child categories [pic rel] with address like [mypage]/product-category/types/. I want to set this generated page as my frontpage which will apear every time user types the name of my webiste. How can I do it?

I cannot use settings->readings->homepage since this page do not appear on regular "Pages" wordpress section.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below function to get subcategories, and than create html accordingly.

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_NAME($parent_cat_NAME) {
  $IDbyNAME = get_term_by('name', $parent_cat_NAME, 'product_cat');
  $product_cat_ID = $IDbyNAME->term_id;
    $args = array(
       'hierarchical' => 1,
       'show_option_none' => '',
       'hide_empty' => 0,
       'parent' => $product_cat_ID,
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
  $subcats = get_categories($args);
    echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';
      foreach ($subcats as $sc) {
        $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );
          echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
      }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```